# SQL Server CE change column type string to int

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Users Table:

[image: User Table]

I want if Role column value is Admin change value to 1,if User change value to 0.After change the type of the column like this Code ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN Role int;

How can I do this with SQL Server Compact query?

Comment: What issue are you facing exactly, and what have you tried?

Comment: I want if Role column value is Admin change value to 1,if User change value to 0.After change the type of the column like this Code ALTER TABLE Users
ALTER COLUMN Role int;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Users  
SET Role =  
  CASE  
     WHEN Role = 'Admin' THEN 1 
     WHEN Role = 'User' THEN 0 
  END
```

Then

```
ALTER TABLE Users ALTER COLUMN Role tinyint NOT NULL
```